# Can only debug once

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, debugging

I can only debug a query once, after that I get this error and have to restart Management Studio.

> Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not connect to computer '(local)'. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Version: 10.50.1797.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I have found I can only debug reliably if I connect the query window to the database using the actual machine name instead of ".".

Comment: Looks like this works. The debugger also launches a lot faster.